# How to trigger an "ErrorBox behavior"?

Tags: programming

Here's an example of what I mean by an "`ErrorBox` behavior".  In the front end, if one evaluates the expression

```
Graphics[Circle[], ImageSize -> Tiny, PlotRange -> {All}]
```

(which includes the invalid option setting `PlotRange -> {All}`), one gets this:

[image]

If one then hovers the mouse over the pink `ErrorBox` (or clicks on the yellow `+` sign), one reads an appropriate error message:

> The specified setting for the option GraphicsBoxOptions, PlotRange cannot be used.

---

Now, suppose I'm implementing some function `foo`.

How can I have `foo` trigger a similar behavior in the front end (say, in response of some invalid argument)?

(By similar behavior I mean the combination of an `ErrorBox` with the mouse-over behavior described above, the yellow `+` and red bracket, the the error message in the Messages window, etc.)

IOW, I'm looking for some built-in function, let's call it `UserError`, such that the expression

```
UserError["The specified setting for the option Frobozz is invalid."]
```

will result in an output featuring a pink `ErrorBox`, etc.

Also, what is the counterpart of the pink `ErrorBox` when *Mathematica* runs without a graphical front end?  For example, just like a user can tell, from seeing a pink `ErrorBox`, that "something went wrong", can an unsupervised script make a similar determination?

**NOTES**

1. Here, to facilitate the description of my question, I've used the low-level construct `ErrorBox` as a convenient visible feature of a high-level behavior (namely the response to an error).  I am **not** interested, however, in the low-level task of creating an `ErrorBox`, per se (as described in the documentation for `ErrorBox`).  Rather, I want to find out how to trigger the high-level behavior that, among other things, has an `ErrorBox` as one of its visible features.
2. Neither `Message`, `Abort`, nor `Throw` trigger the behavior described above.

Comment: It is not clear to me what exactly you are asking. Could you please make a specific foo example with an invalid input and describe exactly what you would like to obtain from MMA?